# How to modelize a threads pool usage?

Tags: uml

Hy,

I tried to modelize a threads pool usage with the following scenario:

- Request a db to retrieve a set of instances
- Create a set of threads, each one doing the same calls set
- start a loop for all retrieved instances

  - wait that one thread is availablle
  - Provides the instance to the available thread that executes its two tasks
- enf of loop

I see [this concurrency question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292305/uml-activity-diagram-with-variable-number-of-concurrent-flows) but it does not modelize a pool.

Any idea ? A fork is like to create a thread so i can not figure how to modelize my goal.

Maybe something like, but this is not correct because StructuredAction does not get a isSynchronous attribute (i did not find one in StructuredAction generalizations)

[image]

Comment: Does it work on retrieved instances only (so all threads are in use until there is no more data) or is it possible that more data comes into the process (so you need to balance waiting for threads vs waiting for instances)?

Comment: What level? Doing a SD? In that case look at `par` fragments.

Comment: it is to provide to a system architect who does not care of details, in fact i think that an asynchronous region could do the job no ?

Comment: do you plan to use some specific diagram to present it (activity? sequence?)?

Comment: I wil in few minutes

Comment: Niormally now there is an idea of schema

Comment: I guess that 'isAsynchronous'  is invented by you?

Comment: Further: what happens to the instances you started and don't wait for?

Comment: yes it almost fills my need, formaly i should create a profile then create a stereotype of StructuredAction and use my stereotype. Heavy to just have a property which exists in CallOperationAction or CallBehaviorAction.

Comment: Humm, at times like this, where you have some actual running code, I find it useful simply to model the object interactions first using an Interaction Diagram and then abstract up, if necessary to another diagram type such as an Activity Diagram. I am confused by what you are asking, and my natural inclination is to analyse -- ask you questions that helps me understand your code, first.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your point, but at this time we have no code.  I just needed to provide an overview of how the code should behave. As I fell, activity diagram and communication diagram are the easiest to undersand for non technical people, so i try to "draw" an activity diagram. I kwnow that my diagram does not care about all details but it helps to communicate on the fact that a threads pool will be used and that long time treatment will be done in dedicated threads.

Answer (score 0):

The schema provided in the question is in fact my answer.